# Aptana 3 : Remove whitespace background highlight/color

Tags: themes, aptana-studio

I'm trying to remove the background color of whitespaces which is affecting the readability of the code. Attaching screenshot to better express my point:

[image: Aptana 3]

The regions pointed by the arrows are the ones I'm referring to. Any ideas/suggestions?

I do not want to change the theme as I've selected the current one after rigorous hours of testing various themes.

Comment: what version are you using?  is this the most current version?  what theme is it?????

Answer (score 1):

I have met with your the same issue, but I resolved it by set the theme configuration:  the BG of "Embedded Source"  -- it means the background color of "Embedded Source" to the Editor's background ...

Analysis of the background color of the editor after applied that theme, then change the theme configure setting of that theme.